# set of images as slideshow

Tags: android

I got 10 pictures.

What I want is when I swipe left it takes to the next picture
When I swipe right it takes to the previous picture

I would like a picture gallery app

here's the link for the - [swiping](https://androidstudies.wordpress.com/2013/05/30/using-swipe-gestures-in-android/comment-page-1/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thats what you need: http://android-kaizen.com/2014/11/23/tutorial-view-pager-with-pagetransformer-animation/

Just follow, it's explained and easy to understand

Answer (score 0):

You could use [ViewPager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/ViewPager.html) for it.